# how to make a gauge view as in the following image in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, gauge

I have looked at the libraries like gaugekit but they does not solve my problem. 
Are there any other libraries for making gauge view as in the image?
If not, then how can I go around about it?

As @DonMag pointed out.
I have tried to make the changes in gaugekit by adding a view on top the gauge view....but it does not turns out to be good.

So I am stuck out at making the spaces in between the actual gauge.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiJ1E.jpg

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] and review [ask]. You say *"gaugekit does not solve my problem"*? You need to describe how you tried to use that, what didn't work for you, and where you ran into trouble trying to modify  it to suit your needs.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `CoreGraphics` and `UIBezierPath`. If you're not familiar with those, though, you might want to do what Ben suggested in his answer.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez I am familiar with CoreGraphics and UIBezierPath but where I am stuck is making the spaces in between the gauge, so if possible can you let me know the way how to make the view if I go with CoreGraphics and UIBezierPath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you create your own custom view, it's not so difficult. Here is how I would do it. I have left out some details for clarity, but you can see in the comments my suggested solutions for that.

First, create a sub-class of `UIVew`. We will need one property to keep track of the gauge position. This goes into your .h file.

```
@interface GaugeView : UIView

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat knobPosition;

@end
```

Next, add the implementation. The GaugeView is a view in itself, so it will be used as the container for the other parts we want. I have used `awakeFromNib` function to do the initialization, so that you can use the class for a UIView in Storyboard. If you prefer, you can do the initialization from an `init` function also.

I have not provided code for the knob in the center, but I would suggest you simply create one view with a white disc (or two to make the gray circle) and the labels to hold the texts parts, and beneath that you add an image view with the gray pointer. The pointer can be moved by applying a rotational transform it.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    // Initialization part could also be placed in init
    [self createSegmentLayers];

    // Add knob views to self
    // :

    // Start somewhere
    self.knobPosition = 0.7;
}
```

Next, create the segments. The actual shapes are not added here, since they will require the size of the view. It is better to defer that to `layoutSubviews`.

```
- (void)createSegmentLayers {
    for (NSInteger segment = 0; segment < 10; ++segment) {
        // Create the shape layer and set fixed properties
        CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

        // Color can be set differently for each segment
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.0;

        [self.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
    }
}
```

Next, we need to respond to size changes to the view. This is where we create the actual shapes too.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // Dynamically create the segment paths and scale them to the current view width
    NSInteger segment = 0;
    for (CAShapeLayer *layer in self.layer.sublayers) {
        layer.frame = self.layer.bounds;
        layer.path = [self createSegmentPath:segment radius:self.bounds.size.width / 2.0].CGPath;

        // If we should fill or not depends on the knob position
        // Since the knobPosition's range is 0.0..1.0 we can just multiply by 10
        // and compare to the segment number
        layer.fillColor = segment < (_knobPosition * 10) ? layer.strokeColor : nil;

        // Assume we added the segment layers first
        if (++segment >= 10)
            break;
    }

    // Move and size knob images
    // :
}
```

Then we need the shapes.

```
- (UIBezierPath *)createSegmentPath:(NSInteger)segment radius:(CGFloat)radius {
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

    // We could also use a table with start and end angles for different segment sizes
    CGFloat startAngle = segment * 21.0 + 180.0 - 12.0;
    CGFloat endAngle = startAngle + 15.0;

    // Draw the path, two arcs and two implicit lines
    [path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(radius, radius) radius:0.9 * radius startAngle:DEG2RAD(startAngle) endAngle:DEG2RAD(endAngle) clockwise:YES];
    [path addArcWithCenter:CGPointMake(radius, radius) radius:0.75 * radius startAngle:DEG2RAD(endAngle) endAngle:DEG2RAD(startAngle) clockwise:NO];
    [path closePath];

    return path;
}
```

Finally, we want to respond to changes to the `knobPosition` property. Calling `setNeedsLayout` will trigger a call to `layoutSubviews`.

```
// Position is 0.0 .. 1.0
- (void)setKnobPosition:(CGFloat)knobPosition {
    // Rotate the knob image to point at the right segment
    // self.knobPointerImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEG2RAD(knobPosition * 207.0 + 180.0));

    _knobPosition = knobPosition;
    [self setNeedsLayout];
}
```

This is what it will look like now. Add the knob, some colors and possibly different sized segments and you are done!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on the image I saw the easiest solution might be to create 12 images and then programmatically swap the images as the value it represents grows or shrinks.

Comment: as much as I understand, won't I have to manage image for each percent if I go by your way

Comment: That is the downside of that solution, yes. But the gauge I saw in the link would result in 11 images. The actual number can be drawn on top of the `UIImage` using a `UILabel`.